APP Flutter no longer opens after updating to IOS 18.1
My APP in Flutter works normally on Android and IOS 16.1, after updating the phone to IOS 18.1 it started to have problems when opening the APP, it could be related to the splash screen, especially because it happens when I try to open the APP and the screen goes black and loads infinitely.
I tried to analyze the xCode splash screen
